# How to wrap a class around the first half of a headline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typography

I'm trying to wrap a class around the first or the second half of a headline so that I could create more dynamic and cool headlines with jQuery.

In theory I want to find all of the spaces in the sentence and divide it into two. If the headline contains an uneven number of words the script should detect that and also add the class to the nearest word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice one @lashleigh. You can have a look at a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/johnhunter/KRJdm/

@Tony, I've implemented what you are after as a jquery plugin. You call it on the header you want formatted:

```
$(function() {
    $('h1').splitWords();
});
```

...and it will produce html output like this:

**Before:**

```
<h1>This is a long headline</h1>
```

**After:**

```
<h1>
    <span class="wrap-1">This is </span>
    <span class="wrap-2">a long headline </span>
</h1>
```

**UPDATED:**

Not part of the original question but I have updated the example to allow you to specify at which word the wrapping occurs. If you provide an index argument it will use that offset on the list of words (minus values count back from the end). e.g:

```
$('h1.a').splitWords();   // Split these words equally
$('h1.b').splitWords(1);  // Split these after the first word
$('h1.c').splitWords(-2); // Split these after the second last word
```

http://jsfiddle.net/johnhunter/KRJdm/

Comment: In my opinion, a plugin is massive overkill, but to each their own. :-)

Comment: @Benson its a fair point. Perhaps jquery is overkill for one piece of functionality. The plugin itself is nothing more than a function wrapping the code you would use anyway, but it makes it easy to reuse. Feel free to rip it out if you prefer :)

Comment: PS: the plugin is 20 lines - including the empty ones :D

Comment: I'd just write a function to wrap the functionality, and call it good.

Comment: That would be just fine :) 'Plugin' is slightly misleading term here anyway - its just a function bound to the jquery namespace. My own view is if the functionality is dependent on jQuery, is DOM related, and potentially reusable then packaging it as a plugin is beneficial.

Comment: I say the same to you Johnhunter as I said to lashleigh - thank you very much. For me, this is another great leap forward for web typography.

Comment: You're welcome Tony. Have updated it a little in case you want to split at a fixed point.

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting problem. I would approach with the handy javascript [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method. Splice can be used to insert and delete items of an array. I'd recommend opening up an inspector and trying out some of the examples I've written below.

First we'll use jQuery to select the header then manipulate the html content string. I'm assuming that the specific header you want to manipulate will have a class and I've substituted 'dynamic':

```
var header = $("h1.dynamic").text();
    => "Header with some other stuff"
var header_as_array = header.split(" ")
    => ["Header", "with", "some", "other", "stuff"]
var first_half = header_as_array.splice(0, header_as_array.length/2)
```

Keep in mind that splice changes the original array, so at this point:

```
first_half = ["Header", "with"]
header_as_array = ["some", "other", "stuff"]
```

Now, you can join them back together and wrap them with spans like so:

```
var first = '<span class="first_half">'+first_half.join(" ")+'</span>';
var second = '<span class="second_half">'+header_as_array.join(" ")+'</span>';

var finished =  first+" "+second;
```

Finally, we'll put our finished string back into the header with jQuery:

```
$("h1.dynamic").html(finished);
```

The way I've written it a header with an odd number of words will always have the second half as the longer half. If you would prefer it the other way around you could do this:

```
var splice_location = Math.ceil(test_as_array.length/2);
var first_half = header_as_array.splice(0, splice_location);
```

By default a non-integer value will be truncated, but here we are using the ceiling function to round things up instead of down.

Comment: Wow, what a service. I've asked the question 2 hours ago and I get this wonderful help. I thank you!

Comment: No problem, I'm really glad it's helpful, and it was a great first question. The best way to say thanks is to mark an answer as 'accepted', this gives the answerer bonus points and generates good karma. I hope that the SO community continues to treat you well.

Comment: Oh, I'm very pussled here. I've alreade accepted johnhunters answer but I really appreciated your way of explaining stuff. I promise that when I reach 15p I will return and vote on your answer as well. I guess you get points for that to?

Comment: That's very nice of you, but I had intended to just give general advice. Last I visited I didn't see an answer marked as accepted, probably just failed to refresh the page or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var headlineText = $('h1.mainHeader').text();
            var headlineWords = headlineText.split(' ');
            var headlineLength = headlineWords.length;
            var headlineMidPoint = (headlineLength / 2) + 1;

            var headlineFirstHalfText = headlineWords.slice(0, headlineMidPoint).join(' ') + ' ';
            var headlineSecondHalfText = headlineWords.slice(headlineMidPoint).join(' ');

            var d = document;
            var headlineFirstHalf = $(d.createElement('span')).addClass('headlineHead').text(headlineFirstHalfText);
            var headlineSecondHalf = $(d.createElement('span')).addClass('headlineTail').text(headlineSecondHalfText);
            var headline = $(d.createElement('h1')).addClass('mainHeader').append(headlineFirstHalf).append(headlineSecondHalf);

            $('h1.mainheader').replaceWith(headline);
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 { font-size:18px;}
        span.headlineTail {font-size:1.2em;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="mainHeader">This is a dynamic headline</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Boy, that's a lot of code. I think the use of createElement and addClass are sort of overkill when you're already doing string manipulations and can pretty easily throw a <span class="foo"></span> around it.

Answer (score -1):

lashleigh's answer is great, however, I would challenge the premise that jQuery is the best choice of technology for achieving this effect. I would be inclined to suggest doing the same server-side. Phrasing the markup using PHP, Python or whatever language you are using and then caching the output with the inserted class. Saves on page weight and means the user's browser doesn't have to calculate everything when each a page is loaded. A significant benefit on light clients such as mobile devices.

Here is an example in PHP.

```
<?php 
        $headline = "This is a headline  of epic proportions";
        $split = explode(' ', $headline);
        $a = array_slice($split, 0, (count($split)/2));
        $b = array_slice($split, (count($split)/2));
        $headline = '<span class="whatever">'. join(' ', $a) . '</span>' . join(' ', $b);
        print $headline;
?>
```

Comment: Absolutely! ...if you're in a position to implement it.

Comment: Interesting thoughts, but this is a trivial operation that will probably take less than a millisecond, even on mobile devices.  Your arguments sound like a case of premature optimization.  The only reason I can see to do it on the server is that you probably have the header text in a variable already -- if that's the case then yes, it'd be worth doing there, because it would mean less code to maintain.

Comment: @Benson I like your point about the maintainability of the code and I would agree that it does appear premature. However, I would argue that one should choose the correct technologies for achieving a task as long as doing so doesn't incur too larger a time or monetary investment. Assuming the site isn't static html then inserting this kind of formatting in the backend would be trivial. Probably simpler code than the javascript. _See PHP added to my post_

Comment: I get the feeling you're a lot more comfortable with PHP than you are with JavaScript.  That's fine -- natural, even -- but you should keep in mind that not everyone is in the same boat.  Also keep in mind that not all websites are built on PHP, and that folks may have good reasons for choosing other platforms.  With that in mind, have another look at the original question: he asks how to use jQuery to do something, and your suggestion simply doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Actually I probably write more in jQuery than I do in PHP these day and could have easily answered answered the question as the questioner asked it (which indeed I began to do so before thinking more deeply on the matter). However, just because a questioner asks you to use a specific technology in a question I feel that if there is a more appropriate technology why wouldn't one use it? According to the mantra of progressive enhancement "enhanced _behaviour_ is provided by unobtrusive, externally linked JavaScript". This is structural not behavioural change to the markup...

Comment: I blogged about this in more detail if you're interested: http://www.pryde-design.co.uk/2011/03/wrap-a-class-around-half-a-string-in-php/